# Different layout result when using Scene Builder (very basic)

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

### My first approach (which works fine)

I have two panes, `gridPane` (inner one) and `borderPane` (outer one). The grid pane is just a row of a few labels, so it is very low. It is designed with the Scene Builder. It gets loaded with the `FXMLLoader` and put into the center of the border pane which is created with the classical

```
BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
```

The size of the window is as expected, nothing is too big or too small.

### The second approach

I use Scene Builder to create the `borderPane` as well, but the grid pane does **not** get put into it right away in the Scene Builder.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
borderPane = (BorderPane) loader.load();
// ...
```

... and later on the `gridPane`:

```
borderPane.setCenter(gridPane);
```

When I run the app now, the window is wider and **a lot** higher.

Side note:
The `borderPane`'s min/pref/max widths and heights all `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. The labels all use only `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. The ´gridPane` has 8 columns, each having min/pref width of 100. But the displayed window is > 1400 px wide and almost 800 px high. Like I said: it works fine if the border pane is created the classical way.

Here are the FXML files for both panes:

### RootLayout.fxml (BorderPane, a.k.a. outer pane)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
</BorderPane>
```

### PlacesOverview.fxml (GridPane, a.k.a. inner pane)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints />
  </rowConstraints>
  <children>
    <Label text="Name" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" />
    <Label text="Montag" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
    <Label text="Dienstag" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
    <Label text="Mittwoch" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
    <Label text="Donnerstag" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
    <Label text="Freitag" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
    <Label text="Samstag" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
    <Label text="Sonntag" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
  </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Can you post the FXML? Consider posting an MCVE.

Comment: @eckig I added the FXMLs.

Comment: I tried this and it works just fine: http://i.imgur.com/LfWupQz.png There must be something else wrong in your code..

Comment: Thanks. Might be a bug in (my) Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe this will help you find the bug: http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/